# Rename batch directory (files) to barcode contained in file image with Zbar (linux)

Tags: linux

Hi I have Zbar working, I did read [Can a picture file be renamed based on a unique barcode contained within the picture?](https://superuser.com/questions/542136/can-a-picture-file-be-renamed-based-on-a-unique-barcode-contained-within-the-pic?newreg=5aed198cbc30441c86570181ac211ca0)  but it was abandoned about 10 years ago.

Basically the script works, in --quiet mode or not Zbar still outputs the Codetype:BARCODEdata, which would provide an invalid file name so basically I need zbar to only output the Barcode and not the code identifier before the semicolon(:)

The script should work regardless of barcode types and if there is more than one barcode in the file a second or third file (respectively) should be created (basically a copy)

I hope this data would be useful to the community

```
   #!/bin/bash
   for file in $*
   do
   name="`zbarimg -q $file`"
   echo "Renaming $file to $name"
   mv $file $name
   done
```

Set permissions:

```
    chmod u+x rename_barcode.sh
  ./rename_barcode.sh *.jpg *.png
```

thanks

Comment: sorry english not my first language its a question to make the script work .  thnak u

Comment: You wrote "the script works", now you want "to make the script work". It's kinda confusing. Also: you used `:` (colon) but referred to "the semicolon". I suspect all the problems can be solved in the shell, even if one doesn't know `zbarimg`, if only you provided few examples of the output from the command, and what names you want to create from each output, respectively. Is the (semi)colon always there? How does `zbarimg` separate results when there is more than one barcode? Make sure the examples cover all aspects and possibilities. Please [edit] the question and clarify.

Comment: the script works relative to the zbar output   at the time zbar would output the barcode number without the prefix of the barcode tpye (CODE128:) example.  sorry im trying my best